# Installation failed please check the installation log and try again in Android Studio

Tags: android

[image]

This error comes every time I download the SDKs for my Android Studio.
I am using Windows 10 PC with 2GB of ram, 32 bit.

The screen shot is uploaded with this issue.

Comment: can you open https://developer.android.com/ in your browser?

Comment: make sure you have a good working internet connection during the process

Comment: @farazkhonsari Yes i can..

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Internet connection is pretty good. But the problem yet persists.

Comment: @AyushiIndani how many times have you retried for downloading because it happens with me too but i keep retrying for 4-5 times. Give it a try and inform me.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I have tried for about 5-6 times in a row and I am still doing it. In your case did it get resolved this way.

Comment: @AyushiIndani yes

Comment: you can check for the memory issue

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Ok .!! Thanks

Comment: @AyushiIndani have a look at my answer below and try for the steps. Let me know it any step helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many reasons for this problem. Here are some reasons :

- When you launch SDK manager, try right clicking on the .exe and selecting "Run As Administrator".
- Also, some anti-virus programs have been known to interfere with SDK Manager (disable antivirus for sometime)
- Make sure Android Studio is allowed to 'Run As Administrator"
- Not enough memory for packages to be installed.
- Interrupt in network connection.
- Restarting Android Studio.

You can check for these issues.

Comment: In my case it got resolved by just restarting the computer. It was some temporary memory issue probably.

Comment: well glad to hear that it was some memory issue. You can approve and verify my answer in case if any other user searches for the same question can get the answer. :)